# хранение массива в базе

Tags: php, mysql

Когда загружаю картинки на сайт, *n* картинок одной формой, то адреса в базу заносятся массивом который сереализую через `serialize();`. Непонятная ситуация в том, что когда вытаскиваю из базы этот массив и хочу привезти его к нормальному виду, то на `unserialize();` мне показывается такая ошибка

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 231 of 231 bytes in /home/urlyogyj/public_html/controller/controller_profile.php on line 621

Я понимаю что, можно ее скрыть и пошло оно, НО! пусть все работает как нужно! наюзал такой вариант решения

```
$img_src = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $data['img_src']);
```

но это не спасло! не могу понять что делать!

Answer (score 3):

все, проблема решена, сообщаю всем у кого может произойти такая же ситуация, нужно быть внимательным с кодировкой файлов. например если делать сериализ и добавлять в базу с одной кодировкой а унсериализ в другой кодировке то будет выводиться данная ошибка! всем бобра...

.. оо святые, как же умен :))))